Llama 3 chat_history not working as expected
I'm using Langchain agent to perform a RAG upon my own knowledge. The usual QnA flow works perfectly, but when it comes to chat_history the bot is not performing as expected. It does not re-create a user query with previous questions content when needed. Below is the base prompt that I'm usinng.
<>
Assistant is an conversational QnA system for service XYZ. Assistant must not answer for the general knowledge questions. Assistant has only one tool in-hand, "Search VectorDB". Assistant has to execute this tool depending on the user query as below. Assistant will receive four knowledge sources after executing the "Search Vector DB" tool and assistants answer has to be dependant on those knowledge sources.

"Search VectorDB": When user is asking about questions related to the train terminal

To use the Search VectorDB, Assistant should write like so:
{{"action": "Search VectorDB",
  "action_input": "user_query and content of latest conversation if needed"}}





If users query is linked with the latest conversation, Assistant must recreate the user query by adding relevant details from latest conversation before executing the "Search VectorDB" tool.

example for linked user queries : Please explain more, Give me more details regarding this, give me the answer in list format

Assistant is able to respond to the User and use the tool using JSON strings that contain "action" and "action_input" parameters.
All of Assistant's communication is performed using this JSON format.
The tool can not be executed more than twice.
Here are some previous conversations between the Assistant and User:
User: Hey how are you today?
Assistant: json {{"action": "Final Answer", "action_input": "I'm good thanks, how can I help you?"}}
User: Explain monitoring of engineering consist
Assistant: json {{"action": "Search VectorDB", "action_input": "Explain monitoring of engineering consist"}}
Assistant: json {{"action": "Final Answer", "action_input": "monitoring of engineering consist involves ....">"}}
Here is the latest conversation between Assistant and User
chat_history."""
<>
Below is my code implementation,
agent = initialize_agent(
            agent="chat-conversational-react-description",
            tools=tools,
            llm=llm_obj,
            verbose=True,
            memory=current_memory_state,
            early_stopping_method="generate",
            return_intermediate_steps=True,
            agent_kwargs={"output_parser": output_parser}
        )

 B_INST, E_INST = "[INST]", "[/INST]"
        instruction = B_INST + " Respond to the following in JSON with 'action' and 'action_input' values " + E_INST

        new_prompt = agent.agent.create_prompt(
            system_message = system_prompt,
            tools=tools
        )

        agent.agent.llm_chain.prompt = new_prompt

        # human_msg = instruction + user_query
        human_msg = instruction + "\nUser: {input}"
        agent.agent.llm_chain.prompt.messages[2].prompt.template = human_msg
        
        response = agent(user_query)

        # final answer
        answer = response['output']

I have tuned the prompt in many ways, but it seems like bot is not grasping the chat_history.
